# Mongo new c++ driver error

Tags: c++, mongodb, driver

When I try to compile my C++ program, I get an error when linking with the MongoDB new C++ driver (mongocxx) that there is an undefined reference.

The problem is easy to reproduce. Just try to compile the test example with in the quickstart guide (https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/wiki/Quickstart-Guide-(New-Driver)). This is the error code:

```
hellomongo.cpp:(.text+0x3f): undefined reference to `mongocxx::v_noabi::uri::k_default_uri[abi:cxx11]'
```

I am using the newest 3.0.1 version of the C++ driver. The error was also there with 3.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

I've replied to your identical question on the mongodb-user list:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/BQvTonyD9pE